# Debug ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed() by setting the breaking point in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, servlets, servlet-listeners

I implement a custom `ServletContextListener` and place the breakpoints on both the `contextInitialized()` and `contextDestroyed()`.

When starting the web application using WTP , `contextInitialized()` can be stopped by the debugger. But when I shut down the web application , the breakpoints in the `contextDestroyed()` do not work and the web application just shutdown . Is it possible and how to use debugger to debug `contextDestroyed()` in eclipse ?

I want to check if the resource used can be released properly during the shut-down of the web application.

Comment: Did you try to create a new empty webapp project and try to debug contextDestroyed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `contextDestroyed()` will only be called when you gracefully shuts down the server by opening the *Servers* view and rightclicking the server instance and choosing *Stop*, or by hitting the red button in the *Servers* view whose tooltip says *Stop the server*.

It will **not** be called when you terminate the server altogether by hitting the red button in the *Console* view whose tooltip says *Terminate*. Terminating (killing) is not the same as stopping.

Comment: Balusc: As the code in contextDestroyed() method is not executed because of the termination(killing), does all the objects that are being initialized in contextInitialized() method will get destroyed?