# GWT Java - Memory Leak - ServletContextListener issue

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gwt, memory-leaks

My friend has set up my application (developed using Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2, GWT 2.6.0, Tomcat 6 - the next release, and the one I am testing on will be Tomcat 7)  on a server and I received this message from him:
"Can you check that there is not a memory leak in the application as I am getting this message when running diagnostics in Apache Tomcat:
The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed), but their

classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus causing a memory
leak (use a profiler to confirm):
/awardtracker"

So I investigated and found that I needed to use a ServletContextListener can clean-up those references. So I found an example; please see below.

I have two questions.

First, what should I be putting in the line "context.setAttribute("TEST", "TEST_VALUE");" in place of "TEST" and "TEST_VALUE"?

Second, when I run the application I receive the message "Context Created" however I do not receive the message "Context Destroyed" when I close the application (I do this by simply closing the browser). How can I destroy the context?

```
package org.AwardTracker.server;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ServletContextImpl
 */
@WebServlet("/ServletContextImpl")

public class ServletContextImpl implements ServletContextListener{ 

 ServletContext context; 

 public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) { 

     System.out.println("Context Created"); 

     context = contextEvent.getServletContext(); 

     // set variable to servlet context 

     context.setAttribute("TEST", "TEST_VALUE"); 

 } 

 public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) { 

     context = contextEvent.getServletContext(); 

     System.out.println("Context Destroyed"); 

 }

}
```

and xml:

```
<listener> 
     <listener-class> 
         org.AwardTracker.server.ServletContextImpl 
     </listener-class> 
</listener>
```

Comment: Off-topic: your usage of `@WebServlet` is wrong.

Comment: You'll have to provide more of the logs. Nothing in this class, if managed by the Servlet container, will cause a memory leak.

Comment: Hi Sotirios, I have changed "@WebServlet" to "@WebListener". Thank you. I have also asked my friend for a copy of the server log. I will post it ASAP. Regards, Glyn

Comment: Hi Sotirios, I have spoken to my friend and he does not have any further information. I will look into what I can run. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Hi Sotirios, I have now installed JProfiler. There are many options (Live memory, Heap walker, CPU views, Threads, Monitors & locks, Telemetries, Databases, JEE & Probes). Which of these do I need to record? Regards, Glyn.

Comment: I've never used `JProfiler`. The code you've posted will not create a memory leak with Tomcat. The issue must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a `ServletContext` as instance member of `ServletContextImpl` class.

Whenever you need it just access it from `ServletContextEvent` as you are doing it already in below code:

```
context = contextEvent.getServletContext();
```

---

In the application you can ccess the `ServletContext` by the [`HttpSession#getServletContext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet).

```
ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
```

For more info have a look at [How to get the Servlet Context from ServletRequest in Servlet 2.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621580/how-to-get-the-servlet-context-from-servletrequest-in-servlet-2-5)

---

**Second, when I run the application I receive the message "Context Created" however I do not receive the message "Context Destroyed" when I close the application (I do this by simply closing the browser).**

Simply closing the browser doesn't destroy the context. Application context is used application wide not only for each client. You can use HTTP session one for each client.

Method `contextDestroyed()` will be called when server is stopped gracefully in the standard way.

For more info have a look at below post

- [Debug ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed() by setting the breaking point in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802457/debug-servletcontextlistener-contextdestroyed-by-setting-the-breaking-point-in)

---

**How can I destroy the context?**

Ideally, the `ServletContext` gets destroyed when the App server (Tomcat or JBoss) is shut down or sometimes even restarted.

Please have a look at below links:

- [When ServletContext is initialized](http://www.coderanch.com/t/354474/Servlets/java/ServletContext-initialized)
- [When is a servletcontext destroyed?](http://www.coderanch.com/t/542328/JBoss/servletcontext-destroyed)

Comment: Hi Braj, Thank you very much. First, from all my reading I still think I have a gaping hole in my understanding of ServeletContext. My understanding was that I add this to assist with preventing memory leaks. I understand now, rightly or wrongly, that it starts and ends with the server and there is no need to do any interactions with it during the life of the application (i.e., no calls in the code beyond that already done in the servelet.

Comment: What type of objects are still in memory even after shutting down the server? `ServeletContext` is used for reading some init parameter form the web.xml and reading properties file single time at application start up or database connection is established or any warm up activities are performed in `contextInitialized()` method. in the same way you can release the database connections or other external acquired resources in `contextDestroyed()`.

Comment: Secondly, Your question prompted me in the right direction. Initially I thought as stated "I close the application (I do this by simply closing the browser)". In hindsight, and reviewing the first point, that is not correct. The application finishes when I stop the server. And low and behold when I stop the server the message "Context Destroyed" is displayed.

Comment: So this just leave the question in relation to "context.setAttribute("TEST", "TEST_VALUE");". Is this required and if so are the current attributes correct or should I set them to something else? Once again thank you very much for your help. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: You are setting a key value in application context that will present till the lifespan of the application until the context is destroyed. If you want to release the memory then you can set it `null` if needed and not required at all. now it depends on the value. how complex is the value? or of what size?

Comment: OK Braj, so I have set "context.setAttribute(null, null);". Now all I need to do is find out "What type of objects are still in memory even after shutting down the server?". I take it that I do this by using something like jprofiler. Once we know this we can use contextDestroyed() to get rid of them. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: call `context.removeAttribute("TEST");`

Comment: If server is stopped then all the object are destroyed automatically because objects resides inside server JVM.

Comment: I have added this. Thanks for your help. Does this mean that I can hand this over to be installed on the server now or do I still need to run jprofiler? Regards, Glyn.